# Confusion regarding JWT authorisation

Tags: jwt

I'm struggling to understand something about JWT authorisation.

Suppose I login successfully as an user. The server will then send me the JWT token that I can use for every subsequent request.

My question is, at this point can anyone on the client side with access to this token technically put it in the Authorisation header and make a request to a protected endpoint and successfully get data back?

Comment: Yes. That is one of the counter-arguments against JWTs. If the token is stolen, the (digital) identity is stolen. As long as the token is valid, the thief can impersonate the user. This is why services like amazon will re-prompt you for the password before, e.g., payment to validate that you not only have the session, but also the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, anyone with possession of that token is authorized. It is up to the application and the browser to protect the token. In your application, you should always:

- Send the token over an encrypted channel (HTTPS).
- Set up CORS correctly, so that the browser can protect your endpoints from access from other applications.
- Use reasonably short token expiration, so that the window when the token can be misused is limited.

Comment: If the token expires quickly wouldn't that require the user to login again to get a new token?

Comment: @blankface  usually there should be a way to *refresh* an expired token (e.g. as an OAuth2 access token or using a session cookie)

Comment: @blankface, to prevent this, a _refresh token_ (or sometimes cookie) can be used. It is a second token obtained during authentication, that has a long expiration and can be revoked by the authentication server. This depends on the concrete authentication implementation.

Answer (score 3):

> at this point can anyone on the client side with access to this token

JWT authentication assumes using an encrypted transport channel (https), so only the authenticated client will have access to the jwt token.  This is generally valid for any token authentication (such as cookie, ...).

Comment: How does one store the token securely on the client? If one uses HTTP only cookies, one is vulnerable to CSRF, for example.

Comment: Ah, so the assumption is that no one can intercept between the server/client and steal the token?

Comment: @blankface well - that's a primary prerequisite that no one can intercept or modify traffic between client and server. HTTPS deals with it (if done properly).

Comment: @blankface, if you're not storing the `token` securely at client, anyone can interpret and steal it.

Comment: @Turing85 IMHO the jwt token shouldn't be stored persistently any way, just used as a transient variable. There's nothing wrong with having session cookies too, but indeed one have to deal with CSRF

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of security, where everything is different.

The topic is more complex as it may seem at first. As was already mentioned, the first step is to protect the token from being intercepted by using a secure connection. But this is not the end of the story.

If the token is securely transmitted to the client, the token has to be stored on the client somewhere. There are three general options:

- Store the token in the session cache, e.g. local storage.
- Submit the token as HTTP only cookie, such that it cannot be accessed by scripts
- Store the token somewhere in the frondend code

Each approach has is up- and downsides. Let's start with local storage.

In essence, the local storage is a big JavaScript object accessible by scripts. In other words: If a script is able to infiltrate your webpage, it is able to read your local storage and thus can steal your token.

Next up, submit the token as HTTP only cookie. This seems well enough. If it is a HTTP only cookies, scripts cannot access the information, thus the information is safe, right? Nope. If a script is able to infiltrate your site and, from this site, makes a request against a secured resource, the token is sent along automatically by the browser (that is how HTTP only cookies work). This is known as [Cross-Site-Request-Forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Finally, one could just store the token somehwere in the script. This seems fine enough, given that one could choose any possible variable name for the token and thus it is hard to guess for the attacker. This holds true, if one writes her/his own code for this part. But mostly, people will fall back on existing solutions and attackers can find the corresponding variable and just read its value. Furthermore, if the token is not stored persistendly that means that a user has to re-login every time the browser is closed and reopened. Depending on the desired UX, this may be not an option.

So there is no "perfect solution" to this problem. It is a "pick your poison" situation. But the story does not end here. As was already mentioned, tokens normally have an expiration date. From a user experience, however, it is bad if the user has to re-login every hour or so, even if s/he was active in that time period. If you take, for instance, the [OAUTH 2.0 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), we have the concept of a refresh token. The refresh token is a special token that, when provided, generates a new JWT access token. The access token can then have a very short expiration time (e.g. 5 minutes). If the access token expires, the client can request a new token by using the refresh token, which is normally long lived, maybe does not expire at all. But this only moves the problem: now the access token is short-lived, but if an attacker is able to get a hold of the refresh token, s/he has the possibility to keep issuing new access tokens. But one can hold the state of a refresh token in the authentication provider, e.g. keycloak has a feature to invalidate all tokens of a user. The question then becomes: how does one notify the system that a token was stolen and all tokens should be invalidated? Or even more fundamental: How does one even notice that one's refresh token was stolen?

The gist of it is: there is no silver bullet. You should look at your use case and decide accordingly. There are best practices, but these may change. And depending on the practice, implementing a new best practice may be time consuming and/or expensive.

Comment: concise and  perfect answer. This answer must be upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you are saying is correct and that is the main reason why any JWT should have an **expiration value**, so that even if it somehow gets stolen, access is limited to a certain period of time (best practices suggest somewhere between 15-60 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

Best practices to store JWT at client,

It should be stored inside an **httpOnly cookie**, a special kind of cookie that’s **only sent in HTTP requests** to the server, and **it’s never accessible** (both for reading or writing) from **JavaScript running in the browser**.

For more details, check this [JWT usage, pros and cons](https://blog.logrocket.com/jwt-authentication-best-practices)